# How to hide # hash in a url using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, url-rewriting

I have a scroll plugin that uses my div ID  to scroll to a specific anchor,

It's creating urls like this: `http://example.com/#examplediv|700`

I want to find a way using js or any other suggested method to hide the hash in the url

I want to transform this: `http://example.com/#examplediv|700`  into this: `http://example.com/`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either modify the scroll plugin you are using or add it yourself on the side but you will want to do something like this:

Assumption: All DIVs that you are concerned with regarding this scrolling will need to have the `anchor-scrolls` class.

HTML

```
<a href="#anchor-hash" class="anchor-scrolls">foo</a>
```

JS

```
//using jQuery
(function($){
   $('.anchor-scrolls').on('click', function(evt){
      evt.preventDefault(); //prevents hash from being append to the url
   });
)(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it, save it and scroll to the anchor, which has the same effect.

```
// Add smooth scrolling to links
$(".anchor-link").on('click', function(event) {

 // Prevent default anchor click behavior
 event.preventDefault();

 // Store hash
 var hash = this.hash;

 // Using jQuery's animate() method to add page scroll
 // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
 $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
 }, 800);

});
```

But works only for anchors at the same page. What if the anchor is at a different page?

Answer (score 1):

The hash is in the `location.hash` property. Just set it to the empty string. If you need to use it in the rest of your code, you can save it in another variable first.

```
var saved_hash = location.hash;
location.hash = '';
```

Comment: That won't "hide it", though, that will remove it (which could be fine if your application doesn't need it anymore).

Comment: My application needs it, but i just dont want it to show in the browser url

Comment: You can save it in another variable before changing the location.

Comment: @Barmar Could you provide me with an example, Im still a newbie in js