# How to not showing the #id in URL with cferdinandi/smooth-scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the smooth-scroll package by cferdinandi, but unable to figure out how to use different selector instead of the ID, so it won't show up in the URL.
For example,

what I want: `example.com`, not: `example.com/#1`

What I did was inserting an `id` to the `div` I want to scroll to, and put the same `id` in the `href` of `<a>` element.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/smooth- scroll@15.0.0/dist/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {
    speed: 800
  });
</script>

...
<a href="#1">About</a>
...


...
<section id="1">
  This is section about
</section>
...
```

It has the functionality, just that I tried to make the URL nicer by not displaying the ids.

Comment: I think it is already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001506/how-to-hide-hash-in-a-url-using-js

Answer (score 1):

I don't kown why the anchor url is bothering you so much. It's helpful when people wants to share specific content on your website.

But if you really want a clean way to do it, try this method:

```js
function goto(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView();
}
```

```css
html {
  /* You don't need any library to achieve smooth scroll */
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<!-- polyfill for scroll-behavior: smooth; -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scroll-behavior-polyfill@2/dist/index.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="goto('1')">Go to 1</a>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="goto('2')">Go to 2</a>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="goto('3')">Go to 3</a>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="goto('4')">Go to 4</a>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="goto('5')">Go to 5</a>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<label id="1">One</label>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<label id="2">Two</label>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<label id="3">Three</label>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<label id="4">Four</label>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<label id="5">Five</label>
```

Comment: I knew this method but it seems to have poor support across browsers, source: https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-behavior